# How to use an ASUS RT-AC87U to extend range of existing RT-AC87U

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I have two ASUS RT-AC87U routers.

One(alpha) is connected to my Google Fiber modem.

The other(bravo) is in another building across the street (110 feet away).

I would like to use bravo to extend the range of the wifi into that office (there is a clear path between the two routers). I have tried Media Bridge mode on ASUSWRT, but that doesn't seem to allow for wireless connection, only hardwired.

What would be the most effective way to accomplish this?

Should I flash dd-wrt onto the router?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you do this by putting the second router in "Access Point" mode and connecting them with a network cable.

Since it sounds like this won't be possible, you could try using the WDS (Wireless Distribution System) feature of your router.  This cuts your wireless bandwidth in half and is less reliable than Access Point mode, but doesn't require the cable.

Comment: Good to know. What about Media Bridge mode? Does it allow for a wireless connection?

Comment: Media Bridge doesn't extend the range of your wireless.  Instead, the router connects to the other router wirelessly, but only provides wired connections for devices.